# CSS border top and bottom with linear gradient

Tags: html, css

I would like to put a gradient border at the top and the bottom of my h2 tags but the border bottom should be the reverse of the top bo.

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: blue;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, orange, rgba(253, 142, 41, 0)) 100% 0 100% 0/3px 0 3px 0 stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class='bloc-content-lower-upper'>
  <h2>Découvrir la technologie</h2>
  <h2>Test</h2>
</div>
```

Here i've got a border top and bottom with this gradient, but i want to reverse the color for the bottom one.
Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use background:

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: blue;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin-right:80px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( 90deg, orange, rgba(253, 142, 41, 0)) top,
    linear-gradient(-90deg, orange, rgba(253, 142, 41, 0)) bottom;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 3px;
 }
```

```html
<div class='bloc-content-lower-upper'>
  <h2>Découvrir la technologie</h2>
  <h2>Test</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic i didn't think about background --', thanks a lot :)